# Setting up DB Schema in Access

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, database-schema

Ok, so I'm not exactly an Access Wizard. I do have a lot of CS experience, but databases are only vaguely familiar to me.

I am creating a database for the cows on my farm, but I'm having an issue setting up a couple tables.

Here are my constraints:

- Each cow only has one eartag at a given time
- Cows are retagged, normally yearly, with different tags. I need to maintain a list of previous eartags for each cow, including the date the tags were changed (for tracking purposes)
- When I load a specific cow, I also need its current eartag color / number to load quickly (I'm unsure if this is necessarily an issue)

What I have so far, is this:

```
      (About 12 other tables are hidden)
```

[image: The three tables in question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm typing this, and laying it all out, it occurs that I don't need the join table *because* I am not referencing the Eartags by Color/Number but rather by a Surrogate Key. Because of this, there is not technically a many-to-many relationship that would occur if I were to use a composite key of Color/Number. (The same tag color, and number, is frequently reused as we re-divide the herds for various reasons)

So, I've now arrived at this solution:

### [image: Updated Solution]

So, as we can now see One Cow can now reference Many Eartags. 
Additionally, multiple cows could technical have the same eartag color/number.
^Side note, I will come up with a way to split cows into herds, and enforce that only one cow can have a given tag color/number at the same time.

***I'm pretty sure this solves my issue, but I would like to leave it incase it happens to be helpful for someone else***